# Remote Management

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac, remote-desktop

When remote management is enabled on a client computer, does the client computer keep logs of when the computer is being observed, when reports are generated, etc? If so, where would this log be located? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for entries containing "ARDAgent" in:

/private/var/log/system.log

/private/var/log/secure.log

The Console application (/Applications/Utilities/Console) is the Apple-provided gui tool to view logs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't find anything useful in system.log, but it shows when the computer is being watched, by which user, and from which IP address in secure.log.